# Pydantic model dynamic field type

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

In my current FastAPI project work, I have following scenario

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class DataSchemaModel(BaseModel):
    Data: Any
```

I will know the Data:(Any) type during runtime(might be some other class type), not during declaration. Is it possible to implement this in pydantic model? Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pydantic's `create_model` to create the class with a parameterized type.
Simple example to create a class where Data is typed as `int`:

```py
from pydantic import create_model

# define your type or class here
data_type = int

DataSchemaModel = create_model('DataSchemaModel', Data=(data_type, ...))

# testing: works
DataSchemaModel(Data=42)

# testing: fails with 
# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for  DataSchemaModel
# Data
#  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
DataSchemaModel(Data=[1, 2])
```